# Unable to save user input into variable using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to take a string as a user input and save it into a variable to use in other parts of my code but I cannot seem to get it working.

My entry widget is:

```
# Entry from user
userInput = tk.Entry(root, width=30, font="Calibri 20 bold", bd = 4)
userInput.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=2)
```

and this is what I tried:

```
def input_text():
    global userInput
    global uInput
    uInput = userInput.get()
```

However I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'uInput' is not defined
```

This is where I want to store the string result

```
test_emails = {'spam': ['renew your password','renew your vows'], 'ham': ['benefits of our account', uInput]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will take user input and store it in the variable "value" and then adds it to a list.

```
import tkinter as tk


sample_list = ["one", "five"]

def get_value():
    user_input = entry.get()
    entry.delete("0", tk.END)

    value = user_input
    print(value)
    sample_list.append(value)
    print(sample_list)
    
root= tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=tk.StringVar())
entry.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command= get_value)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```